# Manga where the main character is raised by 4 demon lords or monsters

Tags: story-identification, anime, manga

So I have little other context than the title but I remember seeing some trailers of it's anime but I can't recall the name at all.

In the trailers it shows a young boy that's raised by the aforementioned monsters/demon lords one of which I remember to have either been a lich or death knight.

I'm sorry for this vague question but I've not been able to find anything on it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You talk about watching a trailer, but you've tagged this "manga."  Is it both an anime and manga?  Also, when and where did you see this?

Comment: Yes it is both a manga and anime, I saw the trailer on youtube and don't know when but I also just found it a minute ago after just searching for "manga where boy raised by lich" and found its name to be Saihate no Paladin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the boy was raised by three such beings, rather than four, then this could be ***[The Faraway Paladin](https://myanimelist.net/anime/48761/Saihate_no_Paladin)***.

From MyAnimeList:

> **Born into a new world after a life of stagnancy, Will awakens to the faces of a skeleton, a ghost, and a mummy. Living in the ruins of a city long fallen, the three raise Will as their own.** The skeleton— Blood—teaches him to fight; the ghost—Gus—teaches him magic; and the mummy—Mary—teaches him religion and responsibility. Most importantly, they all teach him love.
>
> As Will grows up and learns about the world he was born into, he prepares for the day when he must finally set out on his own. For Will, this journey includes a lifelong promise. At their coming-of-age, every adult is required to swear an oath to the god of their choice, with the strength of the pledge affecting the degree of their sworn god's blessing.
>
> With his departure approaching, Will must prepare to accept the truth of his undead guardians and embark into a world that even they don't know the state of. Will discovers, however, that every oath must be fulfilled, one way or another.

Comment: Thanks a bunch dude it is in fact this and I probably got confused by the amount after reading the manga where the guy got raised by the 4 heavenly demons or something.

Answer (score 0):

nvm found it shortly after posting this and searching for hours.

Name is Saihate no Paladin

Comment: Can you supply a summary and a link or any more information to complete your answer?